# Как убрать квадратные скобки?

Tags: python

Допустим
a = [5]
Нужно сделать, так чтобы
a = 5
Как убрать квадратные скобки, но при этом чтобы число оставалось, я знаю как это сделать при print(), а вот чтобы значение было равно не знаю.

Comment: Нужно вытащить число из списка? a = a[0]

Comment: Жмякните на галочку, не лишайте людей баллов xD

Answer (score 3):

То есть, у вас а - это, по сути, список с одним элементом, а вам нужно, чтобы он стал числом, т. е. как раз этим элементом? Тогда нужно просто написать    a = a[0]

a[0] - значит элемент списка под индексом 0, т.е. как раз 5

Answer (score 2):

a = a[0]..............................

Answer (score 0):

Ну если в списке а одно число, то можно сделать так:

```
а = [5]
a = a[0] #это означает что а это первый элемент списка а
```